# Error while creating View in SQL Database

Tags: sql

I am working on database where I am trying to create view to get all records from Art table but i am getting error.

My SQL query for creating the view is as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW artInfo 
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM art 
    WHERE artName = 'Guernica';
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, postgresql, etc... tag it correctly for best results~

Comment: Do you think maybe you could [edit] your question and post the error message that you are getting?

Comment: **Never say “I got an error” without telling us what the error is.**  Cut & paste the exact error so that we can see what it says.  If we can't see the error, we can't tell what the problem is.  It's like taking your car to the mechanic and saying "The car makes a noise" but not telling what the noise is.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks fine, just check table name and column name.

```
CREATE VIEW artInfo AS
SELECT * 
FROM art 
WHERE artName = 'Guernica';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me. I guess this error may come from TABLE artInfo ALREADY EXISTS if you run this code more than once.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE artInfo AS
    SELECT * FROM art 
    WHERE artName = 'Guernica';
```

Otherwise, please update the error and RDBMS for your question.

Answer (score 0):

The basic syntax for creating the view is

CREATE VIEW {viewName} AS {query}